# Macro gives error when updating connections - but only sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

My macro opens up a couple of files, then updates Connections in one of those files. These connections are all pulls from website html tables. The macro worked just fine for a while. Now, when I run the macro, I get this error:

Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

When debugging, the error points to the first connection update line of the macro (Advanced2). Here's the code:

```
    Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TheFormulaFinal V5.xlsm")
    Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\WebScraper.xlsx")
    Windows("WebScraper.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Advanced2").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("DVP").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PrSolu").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Misc").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("NF Project").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("OppTot").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PlrTot2").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TeamTot").Refresh
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("RotoGuru").Refresh
    Sheets("PlrTot2").Select
```

However, the very odd thing is that if I close the two files my code opened (WebScraper and TheFormula V5) without saving, then run the exact same macro, the next time it works! I suspect it has to be some kind of time-related error. I have turned off all background connection refresh as well as any kind of refresh upon file open, so none of these connections should ever update unless they are manually called to do so. I tried using Application Wait to add some time after the WebScraper file opened, and/or after the first refresh, but no avail. I also tried adding some dummy activities after the WebScraper file is activated to see if the file needed some time to load the connections, but also no luck.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's probably related to the usage of `ActiveWorkbook`. That variable depends on which excel file you have open and visible. Better use a direct reference to your workbook.

Comment: @GeertBellekens would it be sufficient to substitute `ThisWorkbook` or do I actually need to use the sheet name in the syntax? If sheet name, could you provide a simple example of what the syntax would be? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workbooks.Open function returns reference to opened workbook. You can use this reference instead ActiveWorkbook.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\WebScraper.xlsx")
wb.Connetions("Advanced2").Refresh
...
```

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you. Thanks to Geert for the idea, and to you basic for the code!